# Google glass development - creating and navigating between cards/screens

Tags: android, navigation, google-glass, google-gdk

So i picked up google glass for my dissertation at university thinking it would be somewhat similar to android java development. I noticed the structure to be the same however i have run into basic problems such as creating and navigating between different activities/cards/screens.

The plan is to create an app which takes and saves notes using the voice API, and while i have started the project where you can talk to the glass, open the app, and choose between creating a new note, or opening saved notes.

I don't know how to go from there.

- Like how would i create a screen
- link it from the new note screen And
- then add the google "start speaking recognition"

Later from there i would like to add a way to save whatever the user has said, and be able to view it in the saved notes part of the application, but that is once ive done the basics.

Any help would literally be great right now.
Thanks

Arron

Comment: As interesting as this question is, it's not on topic on Stack Overflow unfortunately. I suspect google developers will have more information for you.

Answer (score 0):

So far whatever i have learned from your question and email, you have "ok glass" trigger hooked up and you have managed to start the activity. I am also assuming that you have already implemented the GestureDetector in your activity and when user tap on the touch pad, you open up the menu. (If not take a look at [How to implement GestureDetector using Google Glass GDK](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch))

But you are stuck at the menu and trying to figure out that how to open a new slide or card then the solution is pretty simple.

You just need to implement onOptionsItemSelected() method in your Activity and perform check for what user tapped on. For ex, Something like this -

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.newNote:
                Intent searchIntent = new Intent(this, NewNoteActivity.class );
                startActivity(webSearchIntent);
                return true;
            case R.id.savedNote:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SavedNoteActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

And based on the user's tap start an suitable activity. In your case i would imagine, If user tap on "New Note" then you would like to start an Activity called NewNoteActivity which will have Google Voice APIs implemented and ready to trigger the note taking process.

**Important thing to consider  -**

Google Voice API is not capable of doing continuous speech recognition at the moment so you might not be able to take long notes. If you want your app's user to be capable of taking long notes, you might want to take a look into other options like Dragon speech recognition APIs.

I hope it helps.

Cheers,
Varun